# How can I use handleExpandChartChange event to monitor expanded rows in SAPUI5 Gantt Chart?

Tags: sapui5

I need to record the list of rows that expanded in a `Gantt` chart in a `SAPUI5` program.

I found this [handleExpandChartChange](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.gantt.GanttChartBase/methods/handleExpandChartChange) event but there is no attach function for this. Does anyone have any idea that how do we have to use it or any other method to know about the extended rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. We have to use `treeTableToggleEvent` event to monitor the expanded or collapsed rows.

For this we can use the following function as a event handler for `treeTableToggleEvent`:

```
onTreeTableToggleEvent: function (oEvent) {
    var oParameters = oEvent.getParameters();
    if (oParameters.rowIndex >= 0 && oParameters.expanded) {
        if (!this._aExpandedRows.includes(oParameters.rowIndex)) {
            this._aExpandedRows.push(oParameters.rowIndex);
        }
    } else if (oParameters.rowIndex >= 0 && !oParameters.expanded) {
        var iIndex = this._aExpandedRows.indexOf(oParameters.rowIndex);
        if (iIndex > -1) {
            this._aExpandedRows.splice(iIndex, 1);
        }
    }
},
```

For using this function we need the `_aExpandedRows` array to initiate to empty array when we initiate the Gantt chart.

```
this._aExpandedRows = [];
```

The expanded row indices are stored in `_aExpandedRows` array.

I solved the monitoring problem of the expansion of nodes. But still I am interested in how to use `handleExpandChartChange` event.